# Sybase DB - How to store a SELECT query result in a variable?

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to store the result of the SELECT query below in a variable to cut down on computation time. The results are of the form 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ...

```
WHERE
  PEL.kuerzel in (SELECT KL.kuerzel from ictq.KLE KL WHERE FachgruppeKuerzel=526)
```

Right now the SELECT query gets executed 3 times for each of ~2000 entries. If I was able to store the result locally, I would have to run it only once.

I'm working on a Sybase 11 database. How can I achieve this or anything similar?

---

The subquery where the snippet was taken from, out of a 150 line query alltogether:

```
SELECT list(PEL.kuerzel) from ictq.PEpisode PE
INNER JOIN ictq.PEpisodeLeistung PEL ON(PE.IDPATIENTEPISODE = PEL.IDPATIENTEPISODE)
WHERE 
  PE.IDPATIENTKLINIK = P.IDPATIENTKLINIK and 
  PEL.Datum between dateadd(month, -12, @startdatum) and @startdatum and
  PEL.kuerzel in (SELECT kl.kuerzel from ictq.KLE kl where FachgruppeKuerzel=526)
```

I have no control over the structure and cannot add anything. The query in itself is legacy work and I'm happy it works as it is now. The slow computation, however, needs an overhaul.

Comment: Edit your question and show your entire query (or a reasonable simplification of it).

Comment: I added some Details. The query is very large and not my original work, I was just tasked with speeding it up. No idea if the greater scope helps resolve things.

Answer (score 0):

It is often more efficient to use `exists` rather than `in`, or to move the `in` subquery to the `from` clause:

```
FROM PEL JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT KL.kuerzel 
      FROM ictq.KLE KL
      WHERE FachgruppeKuerzel = 526
     ) KL
     ON PEL.kuerzel =  KL.kuerzel;
```

For performance for this query, you want an index on `ictq.KLE(FachgruppeKuerzel, kuerzel)` and `PEL(kuerzel)`.